# Identity involving floor, ceiling and nearest integer functions

Tags: summation, integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For $n\geqslant0$, $m>0$, $s>t\geqslant0$, $n,m,s,t$ - integers we have
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}\left\lfloor{n+ks+t\over ms}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor{n+t\over s}\right\rfloor$$
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}\left\lceil{n+ks+t\over ms}\right\rceil=\left\lceil{n+t\over s}\right\rceil+m-1$$
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}\left[{n+ks+t\over ms}\right]=\left[{n+t+\lceil{s\over 2}\rceil \lfloor{m\over 2}\rfloor+\lceil{s-1\over 2}\rceil \lfloor{m-1\over 2}\rfloor \over s}\right]$$
All of them are self-discovered. I'm looking for nice and simple closed form (and also maybe more simple proof) for the last.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. I do realize that $n, s, t$ come from some context you work in, but as $n$ is unbounded, in your expression you can redefine $n := n+t $ and redefine $t:=0$. That should not affect the formulas.

Comment: @JAskgaard, you are absolutely right, but I sure it is not so significant.